# how to push a video list to rtmp server and keep connect

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Current methods

```
ffmpeg -re -i 1.mp4 -f flv "rtmp://example.com/live"
ffmpeg -re -i 2.mp4 -f flv "rtmp://example.com/live"
ffmpeg -re -i 3.mp4 -f flv "rtmp://example.com/live"
...
```

but 1.mp4 push done later , client and server will be disconnected.
i hope keep connect.

Answer (score 2):

Try concat demuxer.

Create a list (myfiles.txt):

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file '3.mp4'
...
```

Then

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i myfiles.txt -f flv "rtmp://example.com/live"
```