# Show Filename in Video (fmpeg - drawtext)

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

right now, I want to add the filename of a video as text in the video itself. So if the video is in the file 'video2.mp4', there should be 'video2' written in the center of the video. How can I do this with drawtext?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
<sub>Example of file named `smptebars.mp4`.</sub>

Using [Bash parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

```
video=yourvideo.mp4; ffmpeg -i "$video" -filter_complex "drawtext=text='${video%.*}':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:box=1:boxborderw=2:fontsize=18" -c:a copy outdir/"$video"
```

- You didn't mention your OS, so I assumed it can use Bash.
- The example will output to a directory named `outdir`.

Comment: How can i deal with the video list?

Comment: like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803506/how-to-push-a-video-list-to-rtmp-server-and-keep-connect

Comment: @Jim You have several options. 1) Adapt the command in the answer then use concat demuxer to join them. 2) Or use the concat demuxer with drawtext filter using `enable` option and provide the times for each title. 3) Or use subtitles filter with SRT or ASS subtitles.